# How to detect explicit cast operator, should is_constructible work?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, type-traits

I would like to detect, if a class has an explicit conversion operator.
I have tried with is_constructible, but the following assertion fails with msvc 19.00.23506.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo { explicit operator std::string() { return ""; } };

static_assert(std::is_constructible<std::string, Foo>::value, "Fail");
```

My questions would be:

- should is_constructible work here?
- how to detect it in a different way?

Comment: This [sounds familiar](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2118677)...update your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should is_constructible work here?

I think it should, [as there is nothing that excludes explicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible). Both g++4.8 *(and above)* and clang++3.6 *(and above)* successfully compile your code.

---

> how to detect it in a different way?

You can try using the [**detection idiom**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), which was standardized for C++17 but **is implementable in C++11**. *(A C++11-compliant implementation is available on the cppreference page.)*

```
struct Foo { explicit operator std::string() { return ""; } };

template <class T>
using convertible_to_string = decltype(std::string{std::declval<T>()});

// Passes!
static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected<convertible_to_string, Foo>::value, "");
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IREvpkArIM9J27S3)

**(!) NOTE:** this approach doesn't seem to work correctly on MSVC 19.10 *([tested here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/))*. Here's the [full snippet](https://gist.github.com/SuperV1234/568f3bdaccced88294b4cb7725f785ff) I used.

Comment: If even `is_constructible` is borked on MSVC, why would you expect the detection idiom (which depends on expression SFINAE, whose support in MSVC had been notoriously bad/broken) to work?

Comment: I don't use MSVC - I suggested a different approach which may or may not work. I tested it on [this online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) and it seems to report incorrect values. I'll edit the answer to make that clear.

Comment: I wanted to use the check in a conditional template function, this works just fine: typename = decltype(std::string(std::declval<T>())) , hence the accept... Thanks.

Comment: @simon have you tried any "false positive"? (I.e. when T is not convertible to string)

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo yes, it seems to work. Compile would fail on the function implentation, where I convert the templatete parameter to std::string if it would not work, but instead it complains about no applicable overload.